# DataAdapter is not closing connection by itself

Tags: mysql, database-connection, dataadapter

As we know that DataAdapter opens and closes a Connection if it is not already open. But with my code it opens but not close..I am using MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter, not sure what I am doing wrong. below is my code

```
Public Function GetDT(ByVal SqlQuery As String, ByVal ConString As String) As DataTable
    Dim da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, ConString)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    GetDT = ds.Tables(0)
    da.Dispose()
    ds.Dispose()
    da = Nothing
    ds = Nothing
End Function
```

I am using this connection string:`"server=localhost;port=3306;user=someuser;pwd=somepassword;database=mydatabasename;Allow Zero Datetime=True;"`

while debugging the code I found as soon as DataAdapter.fill executes its start a connection thread, but no where connection is getting close as thread remains in SLEEP state . Please check the below image.

[image]

Can any one please help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is the fix, but you should dispose of `ds` before you dispose `da`. Otherwise, you're closing `ds` after you've closed its parent connection.

Comment: I tried but nothing change if I dispose **ds** before **da**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its normal behavior because ADO.NET uses Connection Pooling with SQL Server by default. From MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

> Connecting to a database server typically consists of several
>   time-consuming steps. A physical channel such as a socket or a named
>   pipe must be established, the initial handshake with the server must
>   occur, the connection string information must be parsed, the
>   connection must be authenticated by the server, checks must be run for
>   enlisting in the current transaction, and so on.
>
> In practice, most applications use only one or a few different
>   configurations for connections. This means that during application
>   execution, many identical connections will be repeatedly opened and
>   closed. To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an
>   optimization technique called connection pooling.
>
> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical
>   connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active
>   connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user
>   calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it
>   returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. **When the
>   application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to
>   the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it**. Once the
>   connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.
>
> ....
>
> The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has
>   been idle for approximately 4-8 minutes,...

The effect of "using" or "dispose" in the DataAdapter is the same. "using" ensures that dispose is executed, even if an exception happends. Is the same as using a try / finally statment and put the "dispose" on the finally section.

Comment: I did not get it completely, but it sounds like that DA does not close connection it self.. am I right ?

Comment: It not closes, but returns the connection to the pool, when you call dispose, or using statment ends. If you don't want connection pool for some reason (but is good for performance), you can disable it via ConnectionString, then your connections will close instead of return to the pool. You can do adding ;pooling=false

Answer (score 0):

The connection only closes itself when you use a `Using` directive, the `Using` statement can be used on any object that implements the `IDisposable` interface.

In the Dispose() method of the DataAdapter the connection is closed before disposing the object.
using it correctly would be something like this.

```
Public Function GetDT(ByVal SqlQuery As String, ByVal ConString As String) As DataTable
    Using da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, ConString)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        GetDT = ds.Tables(0)
        da.Dispose()   //because you are now using a 'Using' statement, this method is not necessary anymore.
        ds.Dispose()
        da = Nothing
        ds = Nothing
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your code, its not closing database connection

Comment: Have you tried doing da.Connection.Close() or da.Connection.Dispose()? I am not too sure but I think the DataAdapter has a property to access the connection object

Comment: There is no da.Connection property

Comment: Yes property is there but da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close() does not work to close the connection.

Comment: As above mentioned by IAG , we need to add pooling=false in connection string